# Simulation of Induction motor using Simulink / Simscape

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, dataset, simulation, simulink

I wish to generate a training dataset for a Machine Learning system) of Induction Motor operation using the Induction Motor model in Simulink / Simscape. I am observing the Stator Currents and noting that each simulation run is almost identical to the next. Any idea about how to add variability like a real motor?

Answer (score 0):

In order to see fluctuations, you should change the **load** in your motor.

**Inputs to motors:** Electrical power

**Outputs of motors:** Mechanical power

Motor's input behaves in many cases because of the mechanical load that is connected to it so you should connect **variable mechanical loads** to the output of your motor.